# Generation of OTP in a 2FA email method

Tags: authentication, email, multi-factor

I am aware of the fact that authentication via email is discouraged, but in some specific applications and given as secondary method, we all agree that it may be useful.

Having said that, what is the preferred way to generate OTP to send via email and validate in the application in a 2FA system? Should I use TOTP algorithm and verify passcodes valid in the arch of 10-15 minutes? Or should I just generate a secure random 6-digit passcode (e.g. through [random_int](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php)) and save it temporarily in the database/session data for confronting it with the one provided by the user? Others?

Comment: Are you authenticating the device or user at every login? Traditionally, you don't "use email" to provide the second factor for TOTP: rather, you have a pre-established (ie. pre-shared) **secret** for the TOTP algorithm, and as a user, you provide the currently valid result at time of login (via the login form), thereby proving that you know **secret**. [More: RFC 6238](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6238#section-3).

Comment: @brynk yes, at every login. I know that some applications use TOTP algorithm also for validating passcode sent via email since it guarantees a secure OTP generation, would be that bad idea to implement it or is it better to use a secure random generation like [random_int](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a big difference between using TOTP and storing a random integer with an expiry time.

However, while the later is easier to implement, I would suggest using TOTP for email too, and then let people verify using *either* a normal TOTP token (either hardware or software) or falling back to your email-TOTP if they haven't registered a TOTP. Using the same method for both seems better, and even if you aren't using a normal TOTP today, you should, and this will make it easier to implement it later.

Comment: Given that there have been a lot problems with pRNG in the past, I would also recommend TOTP. You need to avoid, that an attacker can calculate the next OTP value based on a series of previous OTP values. TOTP is considered robust against this attack.